# Open app notification settings in a react native android app?

Tags: react-native

How do I open the notification settings of the app with a React Native code?  I found `Linking.openURL('app-settings://');` for iOS. I'm looking for a similar implementation for the Android platform.

Comment: Try this package and see if it helps, https://github.com/levelasquez/react-native-android-open-settings

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open general app settings you can use: Linking.openSettings()
Also, don't forget import { Linking } from 'react-native'